# Postgresql Misspelling in Full Text Search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using postgresql to perform Full Text Search and I am finding that users will not receive results if there are misspellings.

What is the best way to handle misspelt words in Postgres full text search?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [pg_similarity extension](http://pgsimilarity.projects.pgfoundry.org/) which stuffs PSQL with a lot of similarity operators and functions. This will allow you to add (easy enough) some forgiveness into queries.

Comment: This is something I have been looking for. I will test it out for speed.

Answer (score -5):

By typing "spelling correction postgresql fts" [into google](https://www.google.com/search?q=spelling%20correction%20postgresql%20fts) I get the [top result](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/) being a page that links to just such a [topic](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/pg_trgm/README.pg_trgm).

It suggests using a separate table of all the valid words in your database and running search terms against that to suggest corrections. The trigram matching allows you to measure how "similar" the real words in your table are to the search terms supplied.

Comment: I think this is a little out dated, and talks more about how to search rather than dealing with mispellings.